# jQuery - how to validate a date of birth using jQuery Validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-validate

I want to validate an input ( date of birth ) using jQuery Validation plugin, but it must be in format "dd/mm/yyyy" and also not validate when the date of year is over 2002.

So the date is valid when it's in this format "dd/mm/yyyy" and year over "2002"

Comment: Where is your code?  What have you tried?  [Do you expect a complete solution from scratch?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553)

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find the answer :D this is it. Thanks all

```
$.validator.addMethod("birth", function (value, element) {
        var year = value.split('/');
        if ( value.match(/^\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d\d\d\d$/) && parseInt(year[2]) <= 2002 )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    });
```

Comment: Your regex also allows ridiculously invalid dates such as `99/99/9999`

Comment: 50/50/1990 is valid date. :)